# htmlでリンクを押したらcsvファイルを読み込んでグラフを表示させたい

Tags: javascript, html

#### 実現したいこと

web上のリンクかボタンを押したら特定のcsvファイルを読み込みグラフを表示させる。

#### 試したこと

以下のソースコードはファイル選択ボタンからcsvファイルを選択しグラフを表示させるプログラムです。
これをローカルにあるcsvファイルを読み込むプログラムに変更させるところで行き詰まっています。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dygraph.min.css">
  <title>グラフ表示</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function init()
      {
        var file = document.getElementById('getfile');
        file.onchange = function ()
        {
          var fileList = file.files;
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsText(fileList[0]); // onchange時に読込む
          reader.onload = function() //読込み後グラフ表示
          {   
              ma= reader.result.split("\n"); 
              mas2 = ma.length-2;
              mc = ma[0].split(",");
              function monthplus(x) {
                return x + 1;
              }
              g = new Dygraph( 
                document.getElementById("graph"),
                reader.result,
                {
                    title: '○○○', // タイトル                    
                    xlabel:'日付', // x軸の名前
                    ylabel:'○○○', // y軸の名前
                    drawPoints: true, // プロットの点を出す
                    pointSize: 2, // 点のサイズ
                    highlightCircleSize: 6, // 点を拡大する
                    strokeWidth: 0.0, // 線を消す
                    legend: 'always', // 凡例を常に出す
                    showRangeSelector: true, // 範囲選択バーを表示
                    labelsSeparateLines: true, // 凡例を項目ごとに改行
                    axes: {
                        x: {
                            axisLabelWidth: 100,
                            axisLabelFormatter: function(d, gran) {
                                return monthplus(d.getMonth()) + "/" + d.getDate();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                );
          };
        };
      };
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
  <input type="file" id="getfile" accept=".csv">
  <div id="graph" style="width:1450px; height:700px; margin-left:15px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### CSVファイル

日時, 値1, 値2
2021/02/10 00:00:00, 3.5, 6
.
.
.

#### 参考サイト

https://kurage.ready.jp/jhp_g/html5/localF.html

わかる方よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「決められたcsvファイルを読み込むプログラムに変更させる」をもう少し具体的にお願いします。CSVファイルはどこに置いてありますか？サーバ？ローカルファイル？また「決められたCSVファイル」とは何のことでしょうか？

Comment: @keitaro_so csvファイルはローカルにあります。決められたというのは選択するのではなく毎回同じファイルを読み込むという意味です。

Comment: 参考にしているサイトにも説明がありますが、「ユーザーによる操作が必須」とあります。つまりはユーザにファイルを選択してもらうことが前提条件としてあります。おそらく前提条件である指定するファイルを勝手に読み込むことは難しいと思います。

Comment: 決められたファイルを取得することが難しいので、あげられたファイルが正しいファイルかどうかチェックする方向で仕様を変えたほうがいいかもしれません。

Comment: そうなんですね。
ではローカルではなくサーバー上にあるファイルならできますか？

Comment: 「ajax csv」で検索すればいくつか方法が出てきます。ぜひ一度確認してみてください。